# ENS Name Look Kraken

Tags: etherscan, web3.py, ens

I'm trying to get the ENS for addresses, so I thought initially to use the ENS on web3

```
from ens import ENS
import web3 as w3
provider = w3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
w3 = w3.Web3(provider)
ns = ENS.fromWeb3(w3)
kraken_address = '0x267be1C1D684F78cb4F6a176C4911b741E4Ffdc0'
print(ns.name(kraken_address))
```

However, even for a widely known address such as Kraken this is returning nothing.

So I went to [Etherscan Name Service Lookup](https://etherscan.io/enslookup), still there the Kraken name is not showing when feeding the address above. Any idea, how can one programatically get these public name tags (those that are shown on etherscan) when you directly look up an address, such as the case here [public_name_tag](https://etherscan.io/address/0x267be1C1D684F78cb4F6a176C4911b741E4Ffdc0)?
Is webscrapping  the only solution?

Comment: What is the `0x267be1C1D684F78cb4F6a176C4911b741E4Ffdc0` address in the question? Has Kraken registered an ENS name? Is there an official Kraken announcement on this? You are most likely confusing chain analysed exchange hot wallet addresses with ENS naming system.

Comment: hey @MikkoOhtamaa yeah, the purpose of this question, is to see what is a programatically good way to identify wallets... Like what etherscan offers, when they tag different wallets, I thought originally, etherscan does an ENS lookup, but turns out ENS for many wallets known wallets returns nothing (like Kraken's)...
If you know of a reliable way used in practice, it might help people trying to improve on-chain analysis... Otherwise, I do find the etherscan tag quite reliable, but they don't offer an API for that unfortunately...

Comment: There is no open or public data for who the wallet belongs. EtherScan is your best source and you can use their APIs. However it is highly unlikely you get anything useful there. Otherwise you need to buy this data from companies like Coinfirm.

Comment: thanks @MikkoOhtamaa, can you add this as a potential answer?... also I could not find an api for etherscan that gets the tag... or maybe I am missing something?

Comment: I do not know if they have it or not, as my answer is that "please stop trying doing it because you are not going to be successful".

Comment: I know that the guys on etherscan update the tags manually... based on their own analysis... and they do make the information public... which is great...
note i am not looking for a specific john doe wallet... just like it would be nice to have in your database when you look up MKR contract... you get MKR...
so probably i'll resort to webscrapping , in case no answer is presented... This does work for contracts that are widely known in the community...